# Next.js 13+ How to test global-error.tsx during development

Tags: error-handling, next.js13

I added global-error.tsx file to the Next.js project v 13.4.16.
I am wondering how I can simulate it to see how this looks like in UI during development.

I keep my global-error.tsx file on the same level as root layout.tsx file in app/[locale] directory (since I am using next-intl).

Is there any way to test it?

I have tried throwing an error in root layout file, but it seems to not catch this error. Instead of global-error page, I see Next.js error indicator.

[image]

**Here is how my global-error looks like:**

```
"use client";
import * as React from "react";
import { defaultLanguage } from "@/app/intl";
import { Layout } from "@/app/[locale]/home/HeroSection/Layout";
import { Navbar } from "@/app/[locale]/components/Navbar";
import Footer from "@/app/[locale]/components/Footer/Footer";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Button } from "@/app/[locale]/components/Button";
import Paragraph from "@/app/[locale]/components/ResponsiveText/Paragraph";

type Props = {
  error: Error & { digest?: string };
  reset: () => void;
};
const GlobalError = ({ error, reset }: Props) => {
  return (
    <html lang={defaultLanguage}>
      <body>
        <Navbar lng={defaultLanguage} />
        <Box minHeight={"calc(100vh - 248px)"}>
          <Paragraph>Something went wrong...</Paragraph>
          <Button
            href="/"
            version={"dark"}
            LinkComponent={Link}
            variant="outlined"
          >
            Go back
          </Button>
        </Box>

        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default GlobalError;
```

**And here is how I am trying to test it in root layout:**

```
export default async function LocaleLayout({
  children,
  params: { locale },
}: LocaleLayout) {
  let messages;
  try {
    messages = (await import(`../../messages/${locale}.json`)).default;
  } catch (error) {
    notFound();
  }

  throw new Error("test");
  return (
    <html lang={locale}>
      <body style={{ backgroundColor: "#695E48" }}>
        <NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
          <ThemeRegistry options={{ key: "mui" }}>
            {children}
            <Footer />
            <Analytics />
          </ThemeRegistry>
        </NextIntlClientProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```